# Accessing an extended class method from a sibling extended class (PHP OOP)

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

First off, I am relatively new to OOP as well as using an MVC, so I apologize if I do not use the right terminology or if I seem confused (because I am, haha)

I will start this off as basic as possible and if you need more information please let me know.

I am using Panique's MVC (Version HUGE)
https://github.com/panique/huge

So here goes nothing!

I have a base controller class that is setup like this...

**Controller**

```
<?php
class Controller {

    public $View;

    function __construct() {
        $this->View = new View();
    }

}
?>
```

With some extended controller classes like this (I will show two here)

**IndexController**

```
class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->View->render('index');
    }
}

?>
```

**ProfileController**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function profile() {
        $this->View->render('profile');
    }
}

?>
```

My Question is, what does it take (if at all possible) to use an extended class method within another extended class method when both have the same parent class. Something Like...

```
<?php

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function profile() {
        $this->IndexController->index(); //Here I would like to use the method from the IndexController
    }
}

?>
```

I have tried many of attempts to make this work but I think my lack of knowledge using OOP is hindering me. It seems that most everything I try except for a few cases, throws an error of...

`Fatal error: Class 'IndexController' not found in blah/blah/ProfileController.php`

I think if I could learn to target the extended class the right way I could manage the rest...hopefully ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the file of the class IndexController:

```
require_once('IndexController.php');
$this->controller = new IndexController();
```

Then invoke the method

```
$this->IndexController->index();
```

Comment: This will give an error anyway since $this will not be defined, plus it seems he's using $this in a static method

Comment: Actually, this worked along with `$this->controller = new IndexController()`

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy or elegant way to do that. You would need to instantiate the other class inside the class that needs to borrow the code, and that would probably cause many side effects in your app.

There may be other ways to do that, and that also depends on the possibilities / limitations of the framework, but thinking from the perspective of OOP in PHP, ignoring other factors, the best approach would be to implement the shared code in a method on Controller class:

```
<?php
  class Controller {

      public $View;

      function __construct() {
          $this->View = new View();
      }

      protected function myCustomCode() {
        ...
      }
  }
?>
```

And then call it normally on descendents:

```
<?php
  class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function index() {
        $this->myCustomCode();
        $this->View->render('index');
    }
}

?>



<?php

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function profile() {
        $this->myCustomCode();
        ...whatever...
    }
}

?>
```

I don't see a better way of doing that. Besides, this is the natural way of OOP, where common stuff is up on class hierarchy (ancestors), never sideways or down (descendents). That helps keeping your code logical and easier to maintain.

Comment: @RyanVincent: static methods can access $this, if ran from an object instance.  You have errors only when static methods are called from the class itself (using :: operator). Besides, the example code already uses $this->View->render().

Comment: I assume `$this` is referencing the parent controller class in both the Controller class and Extended class?

Comment: $this refereces the object, not the class. If the object was created as $obj = new Controller(), then $this will be an object of Controller class. If it was $obj = new IndexController(), then $this will be an object of IndexController class. $this never references a parent, it is always the object itself.

Comment: Let me digest that...I having a tough time wrapping my head around it. So `$this` was not declared in the above example , but another object `$View` was declared and added to it correct?

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent I understand a little how the static functions work :) I will adjust my question and replace the static functions to see if it will make more sense.

Comment: Indeed @RyanVincent, you're right! Forgive me, indeed static method don't see $this, even when an object exists.